# ClassCastException being thrown from SpringData's QueryDSL SimpleEntityPathResolver

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, querydsl

I am attempting to use QueryDSL with SpringData plus a Mongo repository.

Here is a simplification of my three levels of a document class hierarchy:

Top-Level Entity class

```
public abstract class AbstractEntity<T extends Serializable> {
    public abstract T getId();
    ...
}
```

Base class for Document (Mongo) entities

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import com.querydsl.core.annotations.QueryEntity;   

@QueryEntity
public abstract class DocumentEntity extends AbstractEntity<String> {
    @Id
    private String id;

    public DocumentEntity() {
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    ...
}
```

Actual entity/document implementation

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.TextIndexed;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;
import com.blah.data.entity.DocumentEntity;
import com.querydsl.core.annotations.QueryEntity;

@QueryEntity
@Document(collection="Manufacturers")
public class Manufacturer extends DocumentEntity {
    @TextIndexed
    private String name;

    public Manufacturer() {
    }
    ...
}
```

The primary version numbers of consequence here, I believe, are

- SpringBoot: 1.5.9.RELEASE
- QueryDSL: 4.1.4

Here is my plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.1.3</version>
<executions>
<execution>
    <goals>
    <goal>process</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
    <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
    <processor> org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoAnnotationProcessor</processor>
    </configuration>
</execution>
</executions>
```

The "Q" classes are generated successfully in my maven build.  However, my QDocumentEntity query class extends BeanPath and my QManufacturer query class extends EntityPathBase. This seems to be the source of the issue.

When I launch my application, I get an exception with the following root cause:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.blah.data.entity.QDocumentEntity cannot be cast to com.querydsl.core.types.EntityPath
at org.springframework.data.querydsl.SimpleEntityPathResolver.createPath(SimpleEntityPathResolver.java:59)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.QueryDslMongoRepository.<init>(QueryDslMongoRepository.java:85)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.QueryDslMongoRepository.<init>(QueryDslMongoRepository.java:67)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142)
```

Based on this error, it seems that the super-class, DocumentEntity, should have been generated as extending EntityPathBase as well.

I'm not sure if it is relevant or not, but the AbstractEntity and DocumentEntity classes are in a separate maven module.

Am I missing something that is required to mark the superclass as an entity to the plugin? How can I force the generator to see my superclasses as entities?

Answer (score 2):

So far, I've discovered 2 things.  At this point, these two things are enough to be a workaround.

I ran the maven build from within Eclipse so that I could step through and debug what the annotation processor was doing.  This led me to my first realization.

My parent class, DocumentEntity, was not being recognized as an Entity in com.querydsl.apt.ExtendedTypeFactory.createClassType(). The initial determined type was TypeCategory.SIMPLE and it never got flipped to TypeCategory.ENTITY because none of the defined entityAnnotations were present on the parent class.  In order for it to be recognized as an entity, there has to be one of the defined annotations: entity, supertype or embeddable. Springframework's MongoAnnotationProcessor defined these as Document.class, QuerySupertype.class and QueryEmbeddable.class.

So, I added @QuerySupertype to my DocumentEntity class and got a different errror.

```
/target/generated-sources/java/com/blah/entity/QManufacturer.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
    public final com.blah.data.entity.QDocumentEntity _super = new com.blah.data.entity.QDocumentEntity(this);
                                          ^
  symbol:   class QDocumentEntity
  location: package com.blah.data.entity
1 error
```

As I mentioned in the OP, the parent class(es) are in another module. If I move the DocumentEntity (with the appropriate annotation) into the same module, it seems to work as expected. The QDocumentEntity class correctly extends EntityPathBase.

I wont' mark the answer as accepted yet, because in my mind it isn't quite answered even though I'm able to make a change and move on.

I don't know if it has to do with the timing of the APT processing for each module or what.

I really would like to have a base "Document" entity class that is in a sharable module and then have specific child modules extend from that and still get the appropriate Q classes generated.  My assumption is that I'm still missing something.

When time permits, I may try to step through the APT processing some more to see if I can get to the bottom of it.